# Wait time in the middle of loop iteration AWS Step Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions, serverless-framework-step-functions

I have an array of data of size ~10000 records. My client API can handle only 1000 records in an hour post which an exception will be thrown. Is there any way I can return the event in the midst of the iteration/as soon as the counter hits 990 and call the next step which introduces a wait time of one hour?

After the wait step has been completed, will my iteration pickup from where it had been left off ?

Comment: I do not want the limit/offset approach

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: One way is to use 2 map state:

- Convert your array to array of arrays:

```
[
   [array1] //contains 1000 items,
   [array2]

...
   [arrayn]
]
```

- Iterate over the array
- for the array inside iterate again and call your API
- pause one hour

Here is the general idea, there is room for lots of improvement, for example you can calculate how much time spent on API call and subtract it from wait time and so on.

Also instead of Map state, it's possible to create a while loop with choice state and achieve the same thing.

[image]

```
{
  "StartAt": "SplitToArayofArrays",
  "States": {
    "SplitToArayofArrays": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Result": "Hello",
      "Next": "IterateFristArray "
    },
    "IterateFristArray ": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "ItemsPath": "$.array",
      "ResultPath": "$.array",
      "MaxConcurrency": 1,
      "Next": "Final State",
      "Iterator": {
        "StartAt": "IterateChildArray",
        "States": {
          "IterateChildArray": {
            "Type": "Map",
            "Iterator": {
              "StartAt": "IterateChildArray",
              "States": {
                "IterateChildArray": {
                  "Type": "Pass",
                  "Result": "Hello",
                  "End": true
                }
              }
            },
            "Next": "PauseOneHour"
          },
          "PauseOneHour": {
            "Type": "Wait",
            "Seconds": 3600,
            "End": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Final State": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Option 2: 1000 records in an hour means that one API call each 3.6 seconds. So add a wait state in map state for 3.6 seconds.